# Prevent Text Overlap

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Good day all,

I have a bit of a dilemma. I have 2 TextViews (as seen in the screen shot)

[image: Text overlap]

And as you can see the Date is going behind the Price.

This was happening when the textviews were in a RelativeLayout. I moved them to a linearlayout and now whats happening is the price is being set onto 2 lines.

What I would like to happen is that the text is laid out as below:

```
Ends 30 Jun... R3,500,000.00
```

Rather than it overlapping like it is in the screenshot.

My Current layout is:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@id/trade_details_include_trade_image"
  android:layout_below="@id/trade_details_include_trade_title"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/trade_details_include_trade_image"
  android:gravity="bottom"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/trade_details_include_trade_ending_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/light_text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_16"
    tools:text="Ends 24 June 00:00"/>

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/trade_details_include_trade_price"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
      android:textSize="@dimen/font_16"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      tools:text="R138,500,000.00"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and when the price is large like R138,500,000.00 it lays out like this

```
                   R138,500,
Ends 22 June 00:00 000.00
```

Now I know there are other SO questions about this similar issue but none of them(that I have found) have given me the solution I need where the date can be Ellipsed off and the price be the priority textview

Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this , it may be help to you

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/trade_details_include_trade_image"
    android:layout_below="@id/trade_details_include_trade_title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/trade_details_include_trade_image"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trade_details_include_trade_ending_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="@color/light_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_16"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/trade_details_include_trade_price"
        android:text="Ends 24 June 00:00" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trade_details_include_trade_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_16"
        android:text="R138,500,000.00"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, I accepted yours as the answer, my solution was still not 100% working but yours works wonders! thank you!

Comment: @x10sion always wlc

Answer (score 0):

a little late but depending on variable text lengths maybe a better solution.

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trade_details_include_trade_ending_time"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="@color/light_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_16"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/trade_details_include_trade_price"
            android:text="Ends 24 June 00:00" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trade_details_include_trade_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_16"
            android:text="R138,500,000.00"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

by setting layout_weights it will fit your layout with nearly any text and will cut the first textview with ellipsize.